# Interesting calculatable properties for integers. Ex: Prime numbers.

Tags: integers

I'm writing a program in java that finds properties for whole numbers, and makes a nice looking list saved as a [text file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIbo2.png) I'm now looking for more properties to calculate.

The program currently calculates the sum of the numbers dividers, and therefore if the number is perfect, poor, or rich. It also checks if the number is prime, a square number, or part of the Fibonacci number series, and lastly it shows all the prime factors of the number.

I want the properties to be calculatable using a general method, meaning not properties such as being the smallest number that can be written as a sum of two cubes in two different ways (1729 is that number btw). And also not too obvious i.e. the program already looks for square numbers, I don't need cube numbers and so on.

If you know of any properties of whole numbers you think fits my description, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I like triangular numbers and hexagonal numbers (most perfect numbers are triangular numbers, by the way).

Comment: Can the number be written as the sum of two squares?  Or three?  Is the number part of a Pythagorean triple?  Is the number the area of a right triangle with integer sides? (ok, that one may be harder).